# Formatting the datetime axis for matplotlib chart is changing the whole graph?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

Here is the original code for the chart which I'm trying to edit the axis for:

```py
# Convert Epoch time from UTC to US/Eastern Datetime
df['EST'] = pd.to_datetime(df['unix'], unit='ms').dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')

# Only care about Hour and Minutes.
df['clean_EST'] = pd.to_datetime(df["EST"].dt.strftime('%H:%M'))

# Use grouper to structure data for chart. Notice I'm using EST for key, not clean_EST
tweet_df_5min = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='EST', freq='5Min', convention='start')).size()

# Plot
tweet_df_5min.plot(figsize=(16,16))
plt.ylabel('5 Minute Tweet Count')
plt.grid(True)
```

This returns:
[image]

The only issue, is I need to format the x axis on the bottom to show for Hour and Minutes, the exact date is trivial for me.

So instead, I will use the `clean_EST` field in my dataframe that only has uses `H%:M%` as the datetime format.

```py
tweet_df_5min = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='clean_EST', freq='5Min', convention='start')).size()
tweet_df_5min.plot(figsize=(16,16))
plt.ylabel('5 Minute Tweet Count')
plt.grid(True)
```

[image]

As you can see, doing so completely changes the order of the chart, by commencing the x axis at 00:00. I don't want to do that, I simply need to change the datetime format to represent the x axis in hours and minutes.

The x axis should be starting at its original position, which starts close to the 20:00h mark.

---

How can I edit X-axis datetime value without my chart looking like a mess? Please point out what I'm doing wrong.

Data for the fields I'm using:

```
df['EST']

0        2022-07-02 20:05:45.021000-04:00
1        2022-07-02 20:05:45.121000-04:00
2        2022-07-02 20:05:45.274000-04:00
3        2022-07-02 20:05:45.269000-04:00
4        2022-07-02 20:05:45.325000-04:00
                       ...               
402864   2022-07-03 01:19:13.348000-04:00
402865   2022-07-03 01:19:13.476000-04:00
402866   2022-07-03 01:19:13.432000-04:00
402867   2022-07-03 01:19:13.493000-04:00
402868   2022-07-03 01:19:13.500000-04:00
Name: EST, Length: 391461, dtype: datetime64[ns, US/Eastern]
```

```
df['clean_EST']
0        2022-07-04 20:05:00
1        2022-07-04 20:05:00
2        2022-07-04 20:05:00
3        2022-07-04 20:05:00
4        2022-07-04 20:05:00
                 ...        
402864   2022-07-04 01:19:00
402865   2022-07-04 01:19:00
402866   2022-07-04 01:19:00
402867   2022-07-04 01:19:00
402868   2022-07-04 01:19:00
Name: clean_EST, Length: 391461, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

EDIT:

```
tweet_df_5min = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='EST', freq='5Min', convention='start')).size()
fig = tweet_df_5min.plot(figsize=(16,16))
fig.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval=1))
fig.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
plt.ylabel('5 Minute Tweet Count')
plt.grid(True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The time data you have appears to be correct, even with the millisecond information. You should leave it as datetime and it should still work. Instead, use `set_major_locator` and `set_major_formatter` for your x-axis to change the range and ticklabels. As I don't have your data, I took the partial data you provided above (EST), changed the hour from 8-20 hrs and crated some dummy y-column data. This is how it looks.

```
                               EST  Ydata
0 2022-07-02 20:05:45.021000-04:00      6
1 2022-07-02 19:05:45.121000-04:00     11
2 2022-07-02 18:05:45.274000-04:00      8
3 2022-07-02 17:05:45.269000-04:00      2
4 2022-07-02 16:05:45.325000-04:00     12
5 2022-07-03 00:19:13.348000-04:00     12
6 2022-07-03 02:19:13.476000-04:00      4
7 2022-07-03 04:19:13.432000-04:00     21
8 2022-07-03 06:19:13.493000-04:00      1
9 2022-07-03 08:19:13.500000-04:00     16
```

The below code for the same was used to create the plot. Note that I have

1. Converted the EST column to `pd.datetime()`, thus the column remains in datetime
2. Used the x-axis formatting to show hours and minutes with 3-hour interval.

**Code**

```
ax = df.plot('EST','Ydata')

import matplotlib.dates as mdates
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval=3))
# set formatter
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
```

The graph comes out this way

[image]

EDIT: If you are still facing issues, can you try these?

- Do a `tweet_df_5min.info()`, The EST column should be `datetime`, not `object`. If it is, use `df['EST'] = pd.to_datetime(df["EST"])`, which is required. I suspect this could be the issue
- The difference between your data and mine is the groupby. See to make sure the data after groupby is ok. If required, tweet_df_5min.reset_index()
- Regarding the 4 hours difference, it is due to timezone. It is basically saying that the time is 4 hrs behind UTC/GMT. So, the local time is eastern North America/South America after you subtract the 4 hrs. You can google this if like

Comment: Not sure why but I'm still getting the same results even when I reproduce your code, please see my edit to see how I implemented. Something to also note and maybe you know the answer, why is `EST` subtracting by 4 ours for every field? `20:05:45.021000-04:00`.

Comment: Hi @andres - Sorry to hear that. I have added some information at the end of the response.  Try the first one, hopeful that it is just a data type issue. Let me know. If none of them work,  pls add the exact output (header and some sample data) of `tweet_df_5min` in the question (use edit and add to bottom). Thanks